# Eloquent join table with two conditions

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have two tables:

**A**: id | user_id | phonenumber | status | ...

**B**: id | user_id | phonenumber | name | ...

I would like to list all elements in table **A** but I have to left join the elements to table **B**.

I can do it with DB:

```
DB::table('A')
  ->leftJoin('B', function ($join) {
    $join->on('A.phonenumber', '=', 'B.phonenumber')
         ->on('A.user_id', '=', 'B.user_id');
  })
  ->select(...)
  ->where('A.user_id', '=', $userId)
  ->get();
```

Is it possible to solve it with eloquent somehow?

Comment: does the on method of $join accept an array as paramter? So you could try $join->on(['a' => 'b', 'c' => 'd']) since '=' is default you don't need to pass it

Answer (score 2):

You can use eloquent, one way is to change it to

```
A::leftJoin('B', function ($join) {
  $join->on('A.phonenumber', '=', 'B.phonenumber')
     ->on('A.user_id', '=', 'B.user_id');
 })
->select(...)
->where('A.user_id', '=', $userId)
->get();
```

And with using pure eloquent

You would have to do adjustment to your A model. We would define two model functions.

```
public function phoneNumber()
{
    return $this->hasMany(B::class, "phonenumber", "phonenumber");
} 

public function userId()
{
    return $this->hasMany(B::class, "user_id", "user_id");
}
```

Now we will change our query to

```
A::with("phonenumber")->has("phonenumber")
   ->with("userId")->has("userId")
   ->where("user_id","=",$userId)
   ->get();
```

This should work for you.

** **Updated** ***

if you want all the record in A then simply do

```
A::with("phonenumber","userId")
   ->where("user_id","=",$userId)
   ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I ran the code and I got less rows than it is expected. Not every item in table A has pair in table B (leftJoin). May I miss something? :/

Answer (score 0):

```
modelname::where(condition)->leftjoin(tablename,fieldname,othertable.fieldname)->get()
```

This is format how we write join in laravel

```
$postdata = post::select('categories.id', 'posts.id', 'categories.categoryname', 'posts.title', 'posts.body', 'posts.image', 'posts.created_at', 'users.name')
            ->where('post_type', 'publish')
            ->where('status', 'active')
            ->where('categories.id', $id)
            ->leftJoin('users', 'users.id', '=', 'posts.user_id')
            ->leftJoin('categories', 'categories.id', '=', 'posts.category')
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
            ->paginate(5);
```

This query display blog with username and with category using join it's my proect convenient query you can also create for you in this manner